# Fill MenuBar on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I try to add a MenuBar to my app, that I develop on macOS and I have a problem where I do not have any idea for:

Works:

```
     QAction *freeNameAct = new QAction(tr("&Settin"), this);
     freeNameAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));

     QMenu *fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File2"));
     fileMenu->addAction(freeNameAct);
```

But does not work:

```
     QAction *freeNameAct = new QAction(tr("&Setting"), this);
     freeNameAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));

     QMenu *fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File2"));
     fileMenu->addAction(freeNameAct);
```

Is the menubar limited in text length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the problem is not the length. You may do something like this:

```
 QAction *freeNameAct = new QAction(tr("&Setting"), this);
 freeNameAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));
 freeNameAct->setMenuRole(QAction::NoRole);
```

Each QAction has a menuRole property which controls the special placement of application menu items; however by default the menuRole is TextHeuristicRole which mean the menu items will be auto-detected by their text. [Source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/macos-issues.html)

In your case, giving the action a text "Setting", it is placed under the application menu, with the text "Preferences..." (which is the default placement and name in macOS) and it is removed from the menu File2.